# printing unicode characters from a tuple in python

Tags: python, unicode, printing

I do not understand this issue where my printing does not work

```
b = (u'\u0648\u0627\u0646\u0627', 'NN')
print b[0]
```

**Output**

```
**Nothing is printed**
```

However this works

```
b = ("haha", "hehe")
print b[0]
```

**Output**

haha

Comment: `b = (u'\u068\u0627\u0646\u0627', 'NN')` assignment shows syntax error for me.

Comment: ...because `\u068` is not a valid Unicode escape sequence.

Comment: I have made an error while copying and have modified it

Comment: What do you want it to print?  If I fix the Unicode error in your example code, it does print something.  Not "haha" but some characters I don't recognize: وانا - which Google Translate from Arabic says might mean "And I".

Comment: I am trying out some arabic text printing and it should print an arabic symbol. Is it an issue with Ipython?

Comment: Make sure to look at the right side of your terminal.  It prints right-to-left.  And make sure your terminal or emulator is configured for UTF-8 display.

Comment: @JohnZwinck yes i think i missed it. Thank you so much

Comment: @aceminer: OK, you're welcome.  I will post something similar as an answer shortly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The answer seems to be that it's Arabic script, which prints right-to-left, so you may have missed it on the right-hand side of your screen.

Also you may need to set your terminal or emulator to UTF-8.

Answer (score 0):

Hey just check you have provided a wrong hexadecimal unicode

```
b = (u'\u068\u0627\u0646\u0627', 'NN')
            ^
```

3 digit hex try using

```
 b = (u'\u0683\u0627\u0646\u0627', 'NN')
 b[0]
```

prints right value as expected.

Comment: Obsolete answer generated from comment.